# Flutter windows build failed after "flutter upgrade"

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

When I create a new project earlier, It told me to upgrade flutter. then I tried upgrading but i couldn't so i used "--force" to forced upgrade flutter. after that i can't debug my flutter apps. not specifically this app also the apps created before the upgrade aren't debugging.

[error-screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OM0O.png)

[error-screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGZ2h.png)

here I attached screenshots of the error that comes up when I 'flutter run' the application.

sorry my english is not the best and thank you for your time.

Comment: switch channel, upgrade flutter, switch back, upgrade flutter again.

Comment: what do you mean by switch channel?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/release/upgrade#switching-flutter-channels

Comment: just tried it. didn't work. the same error comming up

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled the visual studio. now everything is working as usual.